# Adding XML Layout to Fragment

Tags: java, android, xml, android-fragments

I want to include static parts of Fragment's layout in XML file. I've used the default MainActivity and activity_main.xml before without any fragments and everything worked perfectly. Now everything works only partially:

- Button and AutoCompleteTextView are shown in fragment but EditText at the top of the Layout is not.
- OnTouchListeners are never called, same thing with GestureDetection.
- Both onTouchEvent and dispatchTouchEvent are no longer methods aviable to override.
- Listener declared in xml with 'android:onClick="onAdd"' gives me error:"Cannot resolve symbol'onAdd' even though i made this method in Fragment's Java code

  here's my XML file:

  ```
      <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
      xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
      android:id="@+id/to_do_list_fragment"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
      app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
      tools:context="com.rogowiczdawid.smartnote.ToDoFragment">

  <EditText
      android:id="@+id/title_bar"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:background="#AEC2"
      android:focusable="false"
      android:text="@string/title"
      android:textAlignment="center"
      android:textSize="24sp" />

  <ScrollView
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_above="@+id/editText"
      android:layout_below="@+id/title_bar">

  <LinearLayout
      android:id="@+id/mainContainer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:orientation="vertical"
      android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
      android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin" />

  </ScrollView>

  <LinearLayout
  android:id="@+id/editText"
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
  android:orientation="horizontal">

  <AutoCompleteTextView
      android:id="@+id/getTextView"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_weight="1" />

  <Button
      android:id="@+id/add_button"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"
      android:onClick="onAdd"
      android:text="@string/add" />

  </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
  ```

  And the Java code:

  ```
  public class ToDoFragment extends Fragment {

      public boolean title_bar_down = true;
      GestureDetectorCompat detector;
      ArrayList<String> user_list;
      View rootView;

      @Nullable
      @Override
      public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

          rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_do_list_fragment, container, false);

          detector = new GestureDetectorCompat(getActivity(), new ToDoFragment.MyGestureDetector());

          //restoring savedInstanceState
          user_list = new ArrayList<>();
          if (savedInstanceState != null) {
              user_list = savedInstanceState.getStringArrayList("user_list");
              if (user_list != null) {
                  int count = user_list.size();
                  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                      createLayout(user_list.get(i));
                  }
              }
          }

          return inflater.inflate(R.layout.to_do_list_fragment, container, false);
      }

      @Override
      public void onViewCreated(View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
          super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);


          //Allow title to be changed after long click
          final EditText title = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.title_bar);
          title.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
              @Override
              public boolean onLongClick(View view) {
                  title.setFocusable(true);
                  title.requestFocusFromTouch();

                  InputMethodManager inp = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                  inp.showSoftInput(title, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                  return true;
              }
          });
          title.setOnFocusChangeListener(new View.OnFocusChangeListener() {
              @Override
              public void onFocusChange(View view, boolean b) {
                  if (!b) {
                      title.setFocusable(false);
                  }
              }
          });

      }

      @Override
      public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
          boolean handled = super.dispatchTouchEvent(ev);
          handled = detector.onTouchEvent(ev);
          return handled;
      }

      @Override
      public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
          this.detector.onTouchEvent(event);
          return super.onTouchEvent(event);
      }

      public void onAdd(View view) {
          AutoCompleteTextView editTextView = (AutoCompleteTextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.getTextView);
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
              if (!Objects.equals(String.valueOf(editTextView.getText()), "")) {
                  String text = String.valueOf(editTextView.getText());
                  editTextView.setText("");
                  createLayout(text);
                  user_list.add(text);

                  //Change title to first added item
                  EditText edit = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.title_bar);
                  if (String.valueOf(edit.getText()).equals("Title")) {
                      edit.setText(text);
                  }
              }
          }
      }

      ///////////////////GESTURE DETECTION////////////////////

      private class MyGestureDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {

          @Override
          public boolean onFling(MotionEvent e1, MotionEvent e2, float velocityX, float velocityY) {

              final EditText title = (EditText) rootView.findViewById(R.id.title_bar);

              if (title_bar_down && velocityY < -7000) {
                  title.animate().translationY(title.getHeight() * (-1)).setDuration(195).start();
                  title_bar_down = false;

              } else if (!title_bar_down && velocityY > 7000) {
                  title.animate().translationY(0).setDuration(225).start();
                  title_bar_down = true;

              }

              return super.onFling(e1, e2, velocityX, velocityY);
          }

      }
  }
  ```

Comment: Shouldn't you return **rootView** at `onCreateView` instead of inflating a new layout?

Comment: what say the debugger? Is `detector` initilizied? Is the `onTouchEvent` reached?

Comment: returning rootView was the thing when it comes to Button's click listener.